# Extract the "src" from HTML with TWIG

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a piece of HTML where an image is included, for example:

```
<p><img style="etc etc" src="myimage.jpg">Here is some text</p>
```

How can I extract the contents of the src from this HTML? So in the end I want to have myimage.jpg to work with.

I've been trying many things with "striptags" and putting this into a "split" function but I figure there should be an easier way.

*** Edit: reason we need this***
The reason I need this is that a client website is used to add "intro" images in the intro text of an article. We've created a particle that produces a news slideshow with an image and the title of the text on the homepage of the website. However, the image is no separated from the text as it is added to the intro text by the client. Therefor we need to extra the image source from the text.

Comment: What are you trying to do with your link ?

Comment: Basically this is used for a piece of code that uses this for a news slideshow. So you can see it as a bunch of intro texts that are imported into the particle (Gantry5) that contain both the image as the text. The image is taken from the text and shown in some kind of slideshow.

Comment: Extend twig and write a filter which extract the `src` attribute

Answer (score 1):

**Try using This**

```
 Jquery Method->
    $(".image").attr("src");
```

**How does it work ?**

Just simply give that class name to image and it i will look for it. Other wise you would never able to target a specific element .

Comment: Definitely a solution if we didn't need a TWIG solution. Thanks though!

Comment: That's the best solution, I don't think you can use Twig this way, basically Twig is just an enhanced HTML you are not supposed to do such heavy work with it